# integrating PDF reader

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

How can I create a pdf reader in iphone? It should open within the same framework of my application. I have got code for creating PDF files but nothing for viewing a PDF. can anyone help me on dis ground?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIWebView or Quartz to display PDFs.

For UIWebView use this:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 480 )];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"something" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently building an app that uses a PDF document as will. There are 2 way's to display a pdf document, by far the simplest (but slowest) way is using a UIWebView.

The other option is building some sort of reader yourself by using the quartz2d libraries.

Apple has some good documentation on it: [quart2d programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101).

And an Example called [zooming PDF Viewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid WebViews, they are slow and you have no control over them.

The best way to render PDFs on iOS is using the `CGPDF*` set of functions available with Quartz.

Be aware that it won't be super easy. Over time I have found and/or contributed to numerous questions on SO about PDFs on iPhone. Check those out:

[Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints)

[CGPDF iPhone/iPad memory problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915979/cgpdf-iphone-ipad-memory-problems)

[Get PDF hyperlinks on iOS with Quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080373/get-pdf-hyperlinks-on-ios-with-quartz)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a PDF renderer here from apple's code. Just swipe left or right to browse through pages, pinch to zoom etc.

Here is my github.

[Github PDF test](https://github.com/zeroCoder1/PDFtest)