# PDF editing with iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, pdf, ios

I want add some images on existing pdf. After clicking on those images I should able to 
show some animation or able to play music. Is it possible to do that. I am showing pdf page by page using pageCurlUp Animation but I don't know how to show pdf with external Images. There will be different images on different page & with different location. Please guide me how to do that, I am stuck on this.

Thanks in advance,
Jyotsna Kadam

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [example](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/10989-pdf-creation-tutorial.html) to write pdfs. 
here is a [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints) for this issue

great example thats understandable ;-)

cheers Simon

Comment: Hi Simon thanks for your instant reply. I have existing PDF with me but I want to place image on that pdf page. May be on each page with different location. How to do that I don't want to create my own pdf.

Comment: i'd spontaniously say. read the information out and build a new PDF