# While rendering HTML on iPad, How can we create Page Numbers and TOC dynamically? As done by iBooks

Tags: ipad, pagination, ibooks

We are developing an app and we have issue that we want to show page numbers and Table of content for our book shown in our app but we are stuck at the point that how can we get the number of pages while rendering HTML on iPad and iPhone? How can we create Page Numbers and TOC dynamically? As done by iBooks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the closest answers I've seen:

[How do I retrieve a page number or page reference for an Outline destination in a PDF on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643489/how-do-i-retrieve-a-page-number-or-page-reference-for-an-outline-destination-in-a)

Here's some more info I've given others for general pdf info in the past:

[Reading text and images from a pdf document in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732219/reading-text-and-images-from-a-pdf-document-in-ios/5735284#5735284)