# How to get PDF Destination with CGPDF

Tags: ios, pdf, render, cgpdf

I have a pdf file, I want to render it on ipad. But I don't know how to get a named destination and how to implementation of the GoTo Action on ipad.

```
Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > A - 

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > A > **D - iA_userGuide1-4_021311.indd:Document Search**

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > A > S - GoTo

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > BS - 

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > BS > S - S

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > BS > Type - Border

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > BS > W - 0

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > Border - 

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > Border - 0

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > Border - 0

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > Border - 0

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > H - N

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > Rect - 

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > StructParent - 63

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > Subtype - Link

Names > Dests > Kids > Names > Annots > Type - Annot
```

I can get the name, But where can I get the destination with this name. I hope get your help, thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links that helped me:

- [A general overview of PDF on the iOS with many useful links](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3889634/377384)
- [Specifically about getting the destination of internal links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643489/how-do-i-retrieve-a-page-number-or-page-reference-for-an-outline-destination-in-a/4683905#4683905)

Comment: You are welcome. I accept peanuts and upvotes as payment ;)
BTW, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints) would benifit from the code you used to print the page dictionary as shown in your question