# Extract TOC from PDF in iPad

Tags: ipad, pdf

I am developing iPad PDF viewer application for iPad. I am stuck with 2 feature to implement.

- Search and highlight the text in the searched page
- Extract the TOC (outline) from PDF.

Please help me with any pointers will be more than appreciable.
Looking forward to hear back on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same question being answered:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef doc = ...; 
CGPDFDictionaryRef outlinePageRef = ...; 
for (int p=1; p<=CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(doc); p++) 
{ 
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(doc, p); 
if (page == outlinePageRef) { 
printf("found the page number: %i", p); 
break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen an open source solution that has TOC extraction in it. There are a variety of posts on the subject of PDF parsing in iOS on SO. This is one of the top ones with a plethora of information within it, including links to some pointers regarding TOC extraction:

[Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints)

In regards to specifically TOC extraction, it will be very beneficial to read some portions of the immense PDF specification, and also to download Voyeur for os x to look at the actual structure of your PDF's.