# How can i detect Phone number and Hyperlink from Pdf file?

Tags: pdf, ios4, uiwebview

I am displaying my pdf file in UIWebView now i want to detect links and Phone number which is available in my pdf and by pressing link it should open in browser and touching on number it should be called on that particular number so please anybody have idea about it.Give me some suggestion on it.I have written this code for achieving this task but it do not work:

```
 webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 764, 1004)];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Gita.pdf"];
NSLog(@"FilePath==>%@",filePath);
//Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSLog(@"url==>%@",url);

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeAll];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: hey have you find your answer. how we can find links in our pdf and on click of links it should open. i have gone through these links which you have accepted i couldn't find anything.. please can you help me.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link:

http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/tiledlayer_on_the_iphone and http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example.

[Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints)