# AQGridView and PDF thumbnails

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, thumbnails, quartz-graphics

A rather technical question, but it's still a valid one.  I have an app based rather loosely on the AQGridView project.  Does anyone know an efficient method for getting the url's from a cell (objectatindex) and then sending those links one at a time to get a thumbnail of the first pdf page.  After that all I would need to do is just set it as the image for the cell.  I have taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658993/creating-pdf-thumbnail-in-iphone) and found it unsatisfactory as it is non-void and un-dispatch-able.  I've tried calling it in a void method, but it was trying to parse every link at once, and they are very large PDF's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, this [project](https://github.com/raphaelcruzeiro/PdfAnnotator-for-iPad) by Raphael Cruzeiro Illustrates it perfectly.