# Get CGPDFDocumentRef name of document

Tags: ios, cgpdfdocument

Is it possible to retrieve the name of a document from a `CGPDFDocumentRef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "name of a document", do you mean the document filename or title?

If the document "title" is included in the metadata it can be retrieved like this:

```
    char *titleKey = "Title";
    CGPDFStringRef titleStringRef;

    CGPDFDictionaryRef info = CGPDFDocumentGetInfo(myDocumentRef);
    CGPDFDictionaryGetString(info, titleKey, &titleStringRef);
    const unsigned char *titleCstring = CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(titleStringRef);

    printf("title: %s", titleCstring);
```

The other keys are listed in section 10.2 of the PDF 1.7 specification: [Adobe PDF Reference Archives](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html)

Comment: Thanks, I actually mean the filename but my guess is, that that is impossible. Do you happen to know the key for retrieving the creation date from the meta-data?

Comment: "CreationDate", and there is also a "ModDate".

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in Swift 5:

```swift
extension CGPDFDocument {
    var title: String? {
        guard let infoDict = self.info else {
            return nil
        }
        let titleKey = ("Title" as NSString).cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)!
        var titleStringRef: CGPDFStringRef?
        CGPDFDictionaryGetString(infoDict, titleKey, &titleStringRef)
        if let stringRef = titleStringRef,
           let cTitle = CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(stringRef) {
            let length = CGPDFStringGetLength(stringRef)
            let encoding = CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue
            let allocator = kCFAllocatorDefault
            let optionalTitle: UnsafePointer<UInt8>! = Optional<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>(cTitle)
            if let title = CFStringCreateWithBytes(allocator, optionalTitle, length, encoding, true) {
                return title as String
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And here’s my understanding of how it works:

First, we check to see if the PDF document has an info dictionary attached. The PDF info dictionary can contain metadata including the title of the document.*

```swift
        guard let infoDict = self.info else {
            return nil
        }
```

If it does, we try to get the title from that dictionary using the `CGPDFDictionary` API. This API only accepts C types, so we need to perform some conversions to get the Swift String `”Title”` represented as a C string.

```swift
        let titleKey = ("Title" as NSString).cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)!
```

The `CGPDFDictionaryGetString` call takes a pointer to a `CGPDFStringRef?` variable as its third argument. To convert a Swift reference to a pointer, we prepend it with `&`. The result of the dictionary lookup can be nil if the title wasn't specified when the PDF was created.

```swift
        var titleStringRef: CGPDFStringRef?
        CGPDFDictionaryGetString(infoDict, titleKey, &titleStringRef)
        if let stringRef = titleStringRef,
           let cTitle = CGPDFStringGetBytePtr(stringRef) {
```

At this point we know there is a title string, however it's not in a usable Swift string, yet. To read the C string from memory (with `CFStringCreateWithBytes`), we need to know where it starts (pointer) and after how many bytes to stop reading (length). Additionally, we specify that the string should be read using UTF-8 encoding and use the default memory layout. The last item we need is a properly typed reference to the C string. The type of a C string is a pointer to a `char`, which is represented as a `UInt8` in memory. So we end up with `Optional<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>`.

```swift
            let length = CGPDFStringGetLength(stringRef)
            let encoding = CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue
            let allocator = kCFAllocatorDefault
            let optionalTitle: UnsafePointer<UInt8>! = Optional<UnsafePointer<UInt8>>(cTitle)
```

With that information collected, it’s now time to get the Swift String from the C string. Thankfully, CFString is toll-free bridged to Swift’s String, which means we can use the `CFStringCreateWithBytes` call and simply cast the result to String.

```swift
            if let title = CFStringCreateWithBytes(allocator, optionalTitle, length, encoding, true) {
                return title as String
            }
        }
        return nil
```

*The keys for the values in this dictionary can be found in the [Adobe PDF Reference book](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html), TABLE 10.2 "Entries in the document information dictionary" on page 844.

Comment: Could you comment on the answer? This will be helpful to others to understand how it works.

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes Thanks for the heads up, I have added an explanation to the best of my knowledge.