# How to combine pdfs for iOS app

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, merge

Can anyone help with combining two pdf's together on an iPad? I dont know where to start.

I have an app that contains a lot of single page pdf's and I want to be able to allow the user to merge them together for printing and emailing if they wish.

I have looked at the various CGPDF classes but dont know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that I don't have an answer for your exact question, but [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints) is an excellent place to start. When I first started with all of this I used the iText library from Java to see what was actually going on behind the scenes with properties etc (since all the iOS CGPDF classes are Opaque).