# how to find the internal link in pdf file on iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf-generation

I'm trying to find the internal links like Index content in PDF file. Is there any sample for perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best I have found on SO: [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints). Many links and tips.