# How to open web link from pdf in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I m opening pdf file in uiwebview from my app. That pdf contains some web links. But i m getting trouble while opening links from that pdf. Anyone has done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of fun ahead of you :)

Here is the best on SO: [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints). Contains lots of links to other questions based on topic.