# quartz performance for pdf rendering?

Tags: ios, macos, pdf, qt4, quartz-graphics

I have written a simple program in qt4 (linux) that cycles to render 1000 pages from a pdf, putting them on a graphicsview. with the file "Microsoft_Press_ebook_Programming_Windows_Phone_7_PDF" it takes about 1 minute on a amd 2core turion64 1.6Ghz.
I would like to know if performance test for quartz rendering of pdf documents are availalbe somewhere for iOS,OSX. I know that it's not possible to compare my figures to those of such a test but I could have a rough idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a small example app that does the rendering for you. Basic PDF rendering isn't that hard, [look into this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints) for some code.

I can only assume, but PDF is really very deep in Apple's Quartz framework, and when you compare Preview.app with Adobe Reader, Preview is much, much, much faster. I'd bet that using Quartz you can render your pages faster than qt does.

To be sure, you first would have to port your example to a mac, to factor out the component of the OS.