# ipad / objective c - create a low resolution image prior to pdf page rendering

Tags: objective-c, ipad, pdf-rendering

Obviously during the rendering of a high quality PDF, there can be a decent amount of time taken to completely draw the page, I'm trying to find a way to efficiently display a low quality image of that PDF page (ala iBooks) in order to make this wait time sting a little bit less from a user perspective.

Any ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "high quality PDF"? The `CGPDF*` methods in CoreGraphics.framework have rather decent performance for rendering pdf pages.

Comment: Also can you talk about what the source material is you're using for the PDF? You might want to think about generating a thumbnail directly from that source material rather than just create a "low quality PDF page".

Comment: The PDFs I'm using are nothing fancy in and of themselves, they are about 20 MB with text and images. By high quality I just mean that I am not purposefully hindering the quality in any way, just using Apple's example to display the page in a standard manner.

Comment: Have a look at this S.O. resource: [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints) for general hints and a specific suggestion about tiling and performance.