# View pdf files on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints)

Can anyone please point me the right direction. I want to be able to view pdf files on the iPhone and I don't no how to do this. So any tutorials would be great.

I have already done it in a UIwebView. But i am wanting to be able to 'Go to page', 'Print' and 'Email file' can this be done in a UIWebView? if not that's when I want to have the tutorials.

Comment: Quite annoyed that this has been marked as duplicate as it turns out its not. At least the one it has been marked a duplicate of it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already pointed you can display pdf files in standard UIWebView control. Also iOS supports PDF rendering with quartz functions (e.g. see `CGPDF...` family of functions and `CGContextDrawPDFPage` function)

You can also check [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010281) to see how to draw PDF using those functions.

Comment: +1: Typing in `PDFView` in the Xcode Developer Documentation immediately put up this example. It took me not more than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty version would probably be using a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

If you can spend some amount you can get PDF lib for iOS, like FastPdfKit. There are couple of others which will help as well. CGContextDrawPDFPage is a royal pain because you have to parse all the link and other stuff for interaction. If you just want to show use UIWebView.