# Open PDF file from an iOS Application

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

I need to open some PDF files from my App and need some advices.
These files will be on my server and I would open them using a UIWebView.

Do you think it is a good idea or should I do somehow different?
Googling I found something about PDF Kit! Is it better or worst? And why?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience UIWebView is fine for small files without many images.

If a PDF contains many pages or large colorful images then UIWebView may be not very fast to open it. And memory consumption might be high.

In the latter case you might want to use some third-party component or implement your own class. See [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3889634/249690) for some useful tips.

Comment: Thanks Bobrovsky, but I really need to open pdf file: files are not mine, their authors will send them to me in pdf format. I've followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fs-PZvaa47s and it works perfectly! Thanks anyway