# Nested UIScrollViews of PDFs- Uniform Zooming

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, uiscrollview

I'm trying to get a UIScrollView that contains a few UIScrollViews of PDFs.

The same idea as this view in the App Store (just with PDFs and the ability to zoom):
[image: App Store Screenshot Viewer]

I'm having difficulty getting the zoom to work correctly.  How can I have them zoom together at the same time?

How can I achieve this when I can only return one view from this method:

`- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Thanks!

Comment: can u please elaborate ur question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Watch the WWDC 2011 videos, especially "Advanced ScrollView Techniques" [Session 104](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=104) and if you like the [104 Session from 2010](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=104) too. They both handle the aspect of zooming and scrolling with images. Adopting an pdf view (from another tutorial) shouldn't be a big deal.

In your `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` method you can call the other `scrollView` and set a zoom scale programmatically

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == firstSV) {
        return viewForFirstScrollView;
    } else {
        return viewForSecondScrollView;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    firstSV.zoomScale = secondSV.zoomScale;
    // and the other way if you can zoom the second scrollView too
}
```

Comment: +1 I don't think nesting scroll views was really supported until iOS 5, and it was nicely demonstrated in this session.

Answer (score 2):

You should return a container `UIView` to the `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` delegate method.
In this container view you should put all your PDF views side-by-side, as you would images.
Now when you zoom in, the container view will be zoomed along with its contents.
Boom, done.

Except you have to build a zooming PDF view, and make sure you do not load too many pages at the same time to avoid using too much memory.
That's when it gets tricky.

Building a zooming PDF view means either building a view that contains an image that you will render with [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html) and refresh every time it is zoomed in (the scroll view delegate tells you that), or you will have to use [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to render the PDF pages as tiles, saving memory and improving performance.

Not loading too many pages means you will have to add and remove your PDF pages views in / from the container view as the scroll view scrolls.

I did both for a client and it takes forever to get right and bug free (about 3 weeks at least if you're not familiar with the scroll view or PDFKit).
See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints) to get you started if you feel like building it.

The other option is to buy a [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com/) license which is $800 and about 2 hours of integration to get it to work within your app.
After having built a PDF reader myself, I'd choose the second option.
It will save you time and money.