# PHP sort array using another array no keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hello i have an array in php

```
Array
(
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
    [2] => green
    [3] => yellow
    [4] => purple
    [5] => white
)
```

and i want to sort it using that array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 0
    [2] => -1
    [3] => -5
    [4] => -5
    [5] => 9
)
```

so i want the element with the greatest value on the second array to come first on the first array not its value from the second array but the element it self from the first array to move in the first position on the first array! The second bigger to the second place etc.. elements with the same value don't care me how they will be arranged!

the output i want to get is

```
Array
    (
        [0] => white
        [1] => blue
        [2] => green
        [3] => yellow
        [4] => purple
        [5] => red
    )
```

Comment: Oh sh#t. Can you provide example-array of what are you expecting? :D

Comment: maybe there's a better way to do this with a 2-dimensional array...

Comment: Have you tried anything? Take a look at [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

Comment: you can sort the second array and then use its keys in a foreach loop to sort the first array

Comment: yeah i'm making it right now!

Comment: and I was suggesting array_reverse, but you put that in your answer SORT_DESC LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_multisort()` :

```
$ar1 = array(/* your SO links */);
$ar2 = array(/* your numbers */);
array_multisort($ar2, SORT_DESC, $ar1);
```

Documentation [here](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: that was really good thanks a lot dude! Had no idea about multisort!

Answer (score 1):

Use array_multisort.

see http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-multisort.php, follow the "Exemple #1 Trier plusieurs tableaux"

Cordially

Comment: i had no idea there was an array multisort thing so trying it and coming back guys thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Lets call your arrays are $dataArray, and $sortArray respectively

```
asort($sortArray);
foreach ( $sortArray as $key=>$val ) {
    $newArray[] = $dataArray[$key];
}
```

If you need it reversed, just add in a call to array_reverse() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the OP wants is to sort  the first array by the second array's values.

IE- the second array is the vote count for the first array's web pages.

This could be solved more simply if in the first array you have each element as an array with two elements in it, webpage & vote count

```
$pages  = Array
(
    array(
        'page'  => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-ios-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells-e',
        'count' => 0
        )
    array(
        'page'  => 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints',
        'count' => -1
    )
    // etc for the rest...
)
```

But since the question asked how to do it in the current data structure:

```
$sorted_values  = asort($pages);

$new_pages  = array();

$sorted_keys    = array_keys($sorted_values);

foreach($sorted_keys as $page_key)
    array_push($new_pages, $pages[$page_key]);
```

Comment: no its not the votes man it's a sentiment analysis tool for stackoverflow i'm making and that is total ranking