# UIWebview crashing if pdf doc greater than 2 mb

Tags: pdf, uiwebview

I have a webview which loads pdf documents. If the document size is greater than 2 MB, memory warning is received and app is crashing. Is there any limit on the size of the pdf document?

Please reply.

Thanks
Viki

Answer (score 0):

Rendering PDFs with a `UIWebView` is just not right. Any sufficiently complex or big PDF will cause your app to crash. `UIWebView` is good for simple, 1-2 pages long PDFs only.

Please refer to this discussion:
[Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3889634/249690). Some alternatives to `UIWebView` are mentioned there.